What causes my Sourdough bread to bake up dark brown in color?
What causes my sourdough bread to bake up very brown, like a dark whole wheat color, inside and outside? It rises and bakes up beautiful but is very brown. Is it safe to eat? It tastes very good and sour.

To attempt an answer we would need to know your ingredients and preparation method.

A photo or two would help as well.

Without more information this isn't answerable. Voting to close until/unless we know more
